# Execution stopped at readDataToEndOfFile method in iOS

Tags: ios, nstask, nsfilehandle

App execution stopped/hang after "readDataToEndOfFile" method executes. Please find the below code, how to fix this issue

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/sbin/tcpdump"];
    [task setArguments: [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"-l", @"-i",@"en1",@"-A",@"-vvv",@"host",@"www.facebook.com", nil]];

    NSPipe *pipe= [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput: pipe];

    NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

    [task launch];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivedData:) name:NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification object:fileHandle];
    [fileHandle waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];

}


- (void)receivedData:(NSNotification *)notif {

    NSFileHandle *fileHandle=notif.object;
    NSData *data = [fileHandle readDataToEndOfFile];

    NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"result: %@", output);
}
```

Comment: Can you define the "end" of a continuous stream?  You will have to terminate the tcpdump section in order for it to stop.

Comment: @borrrden: I added -c 10 to exit after receiving 10 packets,code below, how can i exit it after 30 seconds instead of 10 packets?

Comment: [task setArguments: [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"-c",@"10", @"-i",@"en1",@"-A",@"-vvv",@"host",@"www.facebook.com", nil]];

Comment: Check the man for tcpdump.  Or try to kill the NSTask after 30 seconds maybe.

Answer (score 0):

try use `availableData` instead of `readDataToEndOfFile`

```
NSFileHandle *fileHandle=notif.object;
NSData *data = [fileHandle availableData];
if (data)
{
// do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is old and seems orphaned, but here's some possibly useful information for those who find themselves here.

Much of the Foundation relating to this issue has evolved. I didn't try to solve the exact problem above. I suspect it involves the `waitUntilExit()` method.

The `NSTask` is now the `Process` class (the documentation for the `init` method says it returns an `NSTask`).

Here's the current implementation of the above in Swift.

```
func tcDump() throws -> String {
    let task = Process()
    task.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/sbin/tcdump")
    task.arguments = ["-1", "-i", "en1", "-A", "-vvv", "host", "www.facebook.com"]
    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    
    let fileHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
    try task.run()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    let data = fileHandle.readDataToEndOfFile()
    
    if let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        return output
    } else {
        FileHandle.standardError.write("problem with tcdump output\n".data(using:.utf8)!)
        throw NSError(domain: "error", code: 1, userInfo: nil)
    }
}
```